# How to get indoor path using react native and google maps api?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to React Native and am trying to implement a simple react app that shows the (indoor) path between two selected indoor locations.

When using the following snippet:

```
          <MapViewDirections
            origin = {this.origin}
            destination = {this.destination}
            apikey={this.GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={4}
            mode= "WALKING"
            strokeColor="hotpink"
            onStart = {(e )=> console.log(e)}
            onReady = {(e) => console.log(e)}
          >
```

I receive the directions using regular streets/roads (basically moving outside the building) even though I selected the "WALKING" mode and both points are inside the building - it would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction (no pun intented).

Comment: I don't believe Google Maps has this ability.

Comment: What confuses me is, if I use my laptop, select the directions manually on https://maps.google.com/ and select the "walking" mode, I can see the indoor path. So it appears that Google does have this ability, I'm just not sure how I can get access to the path.

Comment: https://maps.google.com/help/maps/indoormaps/faqs.html Indoor Maps are only currently available to desktop or for Android devices (native apps). I don't believe the API has this functionality.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!